# Сложносочиненное предложение

Tags: пунктуация

Почему-то Word не подчеркивает пропуск запятой. Я не говорю, что ориентируюсь только на него, но не понимаю, почему он не заметил такую явную ошибку:

За разработку и изготовление арматуры нового поколения взялось ООО «Газпромкомплект»(,) и в мае 2012 г. данная арматура была изготовлена и отгружена ОАО НПК «Уралвагонзавод».

Answer (score 1):

Word нельзя считать авторитетным корректором. Обычно Word замечает только орфографические ошибки.

Comment: Кстати, и этом предложение перед словом Газпромкомплект, у вас стоит запятая и лишний символ. Или это только у меня так показывает?

Comment: Только у вас.

Comment: Странно. И это не только в ваших текстах. Почти в текстах всех участников у меня некорректно отображается тире, кавычки, между буквами лишние символы появляются.

Comment: Возможно у вас проблема со шрифтами на компьютере. Или с браузером.